# A-Frame entities event listener

Tags: dom, events, aframe, entities

Okay so I am working a application where I have loaded a a-scene. Inside that a-scene I have loaded a a-sky and several hotspots(a-image to be more specific)
The issue I am facing is I want to add click listener to the hotspots

this is how i am creating the entity

[image]

the following is the event registration component -

[image]

but still when I click on the entity i did not see anything on the console.

what could I be doing wrong?
i have imported the event registration component in the index.ts file

Comment: Do you have a cursor in your scene?

Comment: I recommend sharing code that people for people to run and suggest alternatives. https://glitch.com/~aframe is great